# how add jquery selection not adding get parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I have the following datepicker.  I want to add the date selection as a get parameter and reload the view.

```
    <script>
$(function() {
    $('#hiddenDate').datepicker({
        changeYear: 'true',
        changeMonth: 'true',
        startDate: '08/16/2014',
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function()
        { 

            var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
            $( "#target" ).submit();
        }
    });

    $('#datepicker').click(function (e) {
        $('#hiddenDate').datepicker("show");
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

    });
});
</script>
```

When I choose a date it now adds nothing in my url after the ? It looks like this:  http://example.com/?

I want it to append the contents of choice and look like this: http://example.com/?hiddenDate=2014-08-16

Comment: What get are you talking about?

Comment: form get. Like <form id="target" action="" method="get">

Comment: question is far too vague

Comment: Add name attribute to your hidden field `<input id="hiddenDate" name="hiddenDate" type="hidden" />`

Comment: window.location = '?hiddenDate='+$(this).datepicker('getDate');

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
                onSelect: function()
                {
                    var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    var targetUrl = $( "#target").attr('action')
                                     .replace(/[?]hiddenDate=[^&]*/, '') + 
                                     '?hiddenDate=' + 
                                      $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateObject);
                   $( "#target").attr('action', targetUrl);
                    $( "#target" ).submit();
                }
```

bye